# How to get user by email?

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I am using graph-service to access Microsoft Graph API. Following this [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graph-service) to get user by email. I have write a block of code:

```
var user = null;
const GraphService = require('graph-service');
const ClientCredentials = require('client-credentials');

const tenant = 'my-company.com';
const clientId = '0b13aa29-ca6b-42e8-a083-89e5bccdf141';
const clientSecret = 'lsl2isRe99Flsj32elwe89234ljhasd8239jsad2sl=';

const credentials = new ClientCredentials(tenant, clientId, clientSecret);

const service = new GraphService(credentials);

service.all('/users').then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      response.data.forEach(function(item) {
          if (item.userPrincipalName == "lgomez@my-company.com"){
            user = item;
            break;
          }
      });
    });
```

But response.data returns a list of users with cost much resource to get a single user object by email. Please help me to update the code which can return only a single object of user by email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation `/users` you are using, is for retreiving a list of all users.
You can request as single user by calling:

> /users/{id | userPrincipalName}

This operation either accepts an `userId`  or an `userPrincipleName`
e.g.

> /users/foo@bar.com
>   [more information is in the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/users)]

In your case the code could be altered to:

```
//...
var myUPN = "lgomez@my-company.com"
service.get('/users/' + myUPN).then(response => {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

Comment: When I change the code to:

service.all('/users/' + "lgomez@my-company.com").then(response => {
            console.log(response.data);
        });

It return an error "Exception has occurred: Error
Error: Resource 'lgomez@my-company.com' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."

Does that mean the user with email lgomez@my-company.com doesn't exist?

Comment: The message sounds more like an code error. Can you try the same request using the Graph Explorer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

Comment: Maybe its because of `service.all` you could try using `service.get`